# Периодичные запросы к внешнему серверу средствами Spring

Tags: java, spring

Разбираюсь в фреймворке Spring и возникла такая задача: необходимо, условно, раз в 3 часа делать запрос на внешний сервер и принимать в ответ html страничку. Собственно, как это можно сделать красиво именно в плане структуры и кода. Можно ли делать очереди заданий, периодичность каких либо действий средствами Spring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В [Spring Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling) есть подходящая аннотация - [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html). Просто помечаете ею метод так:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
public void someTask() {
    ...
}
```

или так

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */3 * * * ?")
public void someTask() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, то, что нужно!